# How can I display wrong predictions in the run/console/terminal for deep learning code?

Tags: python, deep-learning, terminal, conv-neural-network, confusion-matrix

I am trying to display all missed subject (False Positive/False Negatives) onto the run/terminal/console within the IDE. The reason why is because I am using 100 subjects that are separated by two folders (testing and training) and when it finishes the last epoch, it displays the confusion matrix, which looks like this

[image]

As you can see, it is unreadable to see the missed subjects.

Question:
How can I display the missed subjects on the run console?

```
# Importing libraries
import os
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
import numpy as np
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from image_dataset_loader import load
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score

np.random.seed(1000)

# Instantiation
AlexNet = Sequential()

# 1st Convolutional Layer
AlexNet.add(Conv2D(filters=96, input_shape=(227, 227, 3), kernel_size=(11, 11), strides=(4, 4), padding='same'))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))
AlexNet.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))

# 2nd Convolutional Layer
AlexNet.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))
AlexNet.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))

# 3rd Convolutional Layer
AlexNet.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))

# 4th Convolutional Layer
AlexNet.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))

# 5th Convolutional Layer
AlexNet.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))
AlexNet.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))

# Passing it to a Fully Connected layer
AlexNet.add(Flatten())
# 1st Fully Connected Layer
AlexNet.add(Dense(4096, input_shape=(32, 32, 3,)))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout to prevent overfitting
AlexNet.add(Dropout(0.4))

# 2nd Fully Connected Layer
AlexNet.add(Dense(4096))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))

# Add Dropout
AlexNet.add(Dropout(0.4))

# 3rd Fully Connected Layer
AlexNet.add(Dense(1000))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout
AlexNet.add(Dropout(0.4))

# Output Layer
AlexNet.add(Dense(100)) #LFW-CARE
#AlexNet.add(Dense(24)) #FERET
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('softmax'))

# Model Summary
AlexNet.summary()

# Compiling the model
AlexNet.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Josh Plan 1: FERET Pathway
#path = "C:/Users/JoshG/PycharmProjects/Local-Binary-Patterns/Images_FERET/Plan1-DL/Images_AlexNet"
#imgPath = "C:/Users/JoshG/PycharmProjects/Local-Binary-Patterns/Images_FERET/Plan1-DL/Images_AlexNet/Josh_Training_CHD_8I_24S_227"
#testPath = "C:/Users/JoshG/PycharmProjects/Local-Binary-Patterns/Images_FERET/Plan1-DL/Images_AlexNet/Josh_Testing_CHD_24S_227"

#LFW-CARE Pathway
path = "C:/Users/JoshG/PycharmProjects/Local-Binary-Patterns/Images_LFW-CARE/Plan1-DL-LFW-CARE"
imgPath = "C:/Users/JoshG/PycharmProjects/Local-Binary-Patterns/Images_LFW-CARE/Plan1-DL-LFW-CARE/Josh_Training_SEN_8I_100S_227"
testPath = "C:/Users/JoshG/PycharmProjects/Local-Binary-Patterns/Images_LFW-CARE/Plan1-DL-LFW-CARE/Josh_Testing_SEN_100S_227"
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = load(path, [imgPath, testPath])


temp = []
for label in y_train:
    temp.append([label])
y_train = np.array(temp)
# print('-------------------------4')
# print(y_train)
temp = []
for label in y_test:
    temp.append([label])
y_test = np.array(temp)

# Train-validation-test split
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=.12)

# Dimension of the CIFAR10 dataset
print((x_train.shape, y_train.shape))
print((x_val.shape, y_val.shape))
print((x_test.shape, y_test.shape))

# Onehot Encoding the labels.
# from sklearn.utils.multiclass import unique_labels

# Since we have 10 classes we should expect the shape[1] of y_train,y_val and y_test to change from 1 to 10
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_val = to_categorical(y_val)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test)

# Verifying the dimension after one hot encoding
print((x_train.shape, y_train.shape))
print((x_val.shape, y_val.shape))
print((x_test.shape, y_test.shape))

# Image Data Augmentation
train_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=2, horizontal_flip=True, zoom_range=.1)
val_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=2, horizontal_flip=True, zoom_range=.1)
test_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=2, horizontal_flip=True, zoom_range=.1)

# Fitting the augmentation defined above to the data
train_generator.fit(x_train)
val_generator.fit(x_val)
test_generator.fit(x_test)

# Learning Rate Annealer
lrr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_accuracy', factor=.01, patience=3, min_lr=1e-5)

# Defining the parameters
batch_size = 10
epochs = 50
learn_rate = .001

# Training the model
AlexNet.fit(train_generator.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size),
            epochs=epochs, steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0] // batch_size,
            validation_data=val_generator.flow(x_val, y_val, batch_size=batch_size),
            validation_steps=2, callbacks=[lrr], verbose=1)

# After successful training, we will visualize its performance.

# Plotting the training and validation loss
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)  # Creates 2 subplots under 1 column

# Assigning the first subplot to graph training loss and validation loss
ax.plot(AlexNet.history.history['loss'], color='b', label='Training Loss')
ax.plot(AlexNet.history.history['val_loss'], color='r', label='Validation Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)  # Creates 2 subplots under 1 column

# Plotting the training accuracy and validation accuracy
ax.plot(AlexNet.history.history['accuracy'], color='b', label='Training Accuracy')
ax.plot(AlexNet.history.history['val_accuracy'], color='r', label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


# Defining function for confusion matrix plot
def plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title=None,
                          cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    if not title:
        if normalize:
            title = 'Normalized confusion matrix'
        else:
            title = 'Confusion matrix, without normalization'

    # Compute confusion matrix
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Normalized confusion matrix")
    else:
        print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

    # Print Confusion matrix
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))
    im = ax.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
    # We want to show all ticks...
    ax.set(xticks=np.arange(cm.shape[1]),
           yticks=np.arange(cm.shape[0]),
           xticklabels=classes, yticklabels=classes,
           title=title,
           ylabel='True label',
           xlabel='Predicted label')

    # Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
             rotation_mode="anchor")
    # Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations.
    fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i in range(cm.shape[0]):
        for j in range(cm.shape[1]):
            ax.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
                    ha="center", color="white"
                if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")
    plt.tight_layout()
    return ax


np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

# Making prediction
y_pred = (AlexNet.predict_classes(x_test))
y_true = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)
print(y_pred)
print(y_pred.shape)

# Plotting the confusion matrix
confusion_mtx = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)

# class_names=['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']
CLASS_NAMES = [f.name for f in os.scandir(imgPath) if f.is_dir()]
class_names = CLASS_NAMES
print(class_names)

print("ypred\n", y_pred)
print("ytrue", y_true)

# Plotting non-normalized confusion matrix
plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, classes=class_names, title='AlexNet Confusion matrix, without normalization')
plt.show()

# Plotting normalized confusion matrix
# plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, classes=class_names, normalize=True, title='Normalized confusion matrix')
# plt.show()

# Classification Metrics
acc_score = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
print('\n\n\t\t  Accuracy Score: ', str(round((100 * acc_score), 2)), '%')
prec_score = precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
print('   Precision Score Macro: ', str(round((100 * prec_score), 2)), '%')
prec_score = precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro')
print('   Precision Score Micro: ', str(round((100 * prec_score), 2)), '%')
prec_score = precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted')
print('Precision Score Weighted: ', str(round((100 * prec_score), 2)), '%')
rec_score = recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
print('\t\t\tRecall Macro: ', str(round((100 * rec_score), 2)), '%')
rec_score = recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro')
print('\t\t\tRecall Micro: ', str(round((100 * rec_score), 2)), '%')
rec_score = recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted')
print('\t\t Recall Weighted: ', str(round((100 * rec_score), 2)), '%')
f_score = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
print('\t\t  F1 Score Macro: ', str(round((100 * f_score), 2)), '%')
f_score = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro')
print('\t\t  F1 Score Micro: ', str(round((100 * f_score), 2)), '%')
f_score = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted')
print('\t   F1 Score Weighted: ', str(round((100 * f_score), 2)), '%')
```

Comment: just use a for loop and compare y_pred and y_true, print the values for which the labels dont match?

Comment: I am new to python, so where would I add that?

Comment: i would suggest learning the basics of programming not just python before you delve into ML.

Comment: Not really helpful

Comment: sorry i wasnt trying to be mean. just saying you should learn the basics first.

Answer (score 1):

just add a for loop to print where the predictions are wrong by comparing y_true and y_pred at the end.

```
.
.
.
uniq = set()
for i in range(len(y_pred)):
    if y_pred[i] != y_true[i]:
        uniq.add(y_pred[i])
        
print(uniq)
.
.
.
```

obviously this prints the labels that were mis classified, if you only want the unique values you can append them to a set() or store the associated index i and use that to print whatever information you need.

Comment: Ahh it make sense. Thank you again Ritwick. My basic was learning it as part of DL or ML. So I had to learn the basic and implement part of it. So no worries.

Comment: printing this to the console would not be very helpful. do you just want to know which labels were missed at least once? then use a set and print the set, if you want to know the frequency of each label being mis classified you can use a dict or simply use the confusion matrix and print the label with (total num - true positive)

Comment: I just want them to print the missed labels only, with labels (Unique values) as well

Comment: okay i updated it